# HERE API autosuggest 503 service unavailable

Tags: here-api, autosuggest

We have been getting **503 Service Unavailable** responses recently using the **HERE API autosuggest** endpoint. When it occurs, it can last for hours. Below is a typical request we get a 503 response from:

https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?q=Bradford&at=52.8,-1.4&addressFilter=countryCode=GB&result_types=address,place&app_code=########&app_id=###########

We have been using this service for a long while now and majority of the time the endpoint responds as expected. However, we are using it in a production environment, so any downtime (especially hours) is not good. Can we do anything when **503** occurs (E.g. calling a different endpoint)?

Thank you for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no you cannot, outside of ensuring your application itself responds correctly to the error. You can also bookmark our status page (https://status.here.com/status) for more information when something goes wrong. I'm sorry the API was flakey for you recently, but hopefully this is just a temporary issue and doesn't return.

Comment: Hi Raymond, appreciate your response. I did look at the system status page you linked to prior to posting, but it indicated "normal operation" on those days for "Search" service. Thanks again